# super and property inheritance in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have created a `USer` class and created a subclass `ADmin`

```
class USer {

    constructor(public name: string, public employees: string[]) {  // wieso dann hier nochmal type zuordnen dachte das wäre das gleiche oder ?
      }
       login(this: User){   
     
      }
  

}

class ADmin extends USer {

    constructor(name: string, employes: string[], public admin: string){
        super(name, employes); // calls the constructor of the USer !
    }


}
```

As I understood  `super()`  calls the constructor function of `USer`, so all properties are inherited to the subclass.

If I dont declare the property types I get

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

why do I need to  declare the types of the properties in the `ADmin` class again ? should there type not be transferred to `ADmin`?

Comment: You don't, but in this case you want the parameters so that you can pass this off to the parent... but you can have any type of constructor parameters. Such definition could be `constructor(public admin: string){ super("James", ["Sarah", "John"]);}`

Comment: sorry I dont understand your explanation, I edited my question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types in your constructor are doing two things:

1. They declare the types for the arguments that are passed to the constructor
2. They declare the types for the instance variable of the class

#1 is a requirement of all `constructor` functions.  #2 is just a shortcut to make your life easier, and only occurs when you use a modifier like `public` before the variable.

When you declare that `class Admin extends User`, `Admin` inherits all of the types from #2.  It knows that an `Admin` instance must have a `name` and `employees`.  It does **not** inherit the types from #1.

The only rule for the `Admin` `constructor` is that it must call `super(name, employees)` with arguments `(string, string[])`.  It does not need to follow the same format as the `User` constructor.  It could accept the arguments in a different order, use any number of any type of arguments to derive the `name` and `employees`, or even accept zero arguments and call `super` with some predefined constant.

Here are a few silly examples of constructors which are all valid

```
constructor(name: string[]){
  super(name[0], []); // derive name, create employees
}
```

```
constructor(object: {name: string, employees: string[]}){
    super(object.name, object.employees); // derive name & employees
}
```

```
constructor(){
    super("The Admin", []); // create name & employees
}
```

```
constructor(name: string[], employees: string){
    super(employees, name); // TERRIBLE code with backwards variables
}
```

That last one (which is awful code that you should never write) is to demonstrate that you can have the same variables `name` and `employees` in the same order as the `User` constructor and not share the same types.  So that is why the #1 types are not inherited.

To summarize:

> As I understood super() calls the constructor function of USer, so all properties are inherited to the subclass.

This is correct.

> why do I need to declare the types of the properties in the ADmin class again ? should there type not be transferred to ADmin?

You are not declaring the types of the properties.  You are declaring the types of the function arguments for the `constructor` function.